# initialize variable in constructor

Tags: c++, oop, object, inheritance, constructor

```
 #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class aclass
{
   public:

   int a;
};

class cclass: public aclass
{
   public:  
   cclass()
   {
      a= //what do i write here//
   }
}

class bclass : public aclass 
{
public:
   bclass()
   {
      a=9;     //a is not constant here. I have just taken it const for simplicity.
   }

 int func();
};


int bclass::func()
{
   cclass * ob;
   ob = new cclass(); 
}
```

How do i make the value of variable a for an object of cclass equal to the value of a of the object of bclass which creates it(the object of cclass). I can do it in the function func()
by doing

```
ob->a = a;
```

but how do i do it in the constructor of cclass?

Comment: I would re-read that chapter in the book

Comment: I wrote an answer, but then deleted it since you don't seem to understand the fundamentals of the code you're attempting to write.  What is your goal here?

Comment: At the point where you have `new cclass` the type `cclass` has not yet been declared, so this is **not real code**.

Comment: @RyanHaining  At run time, for different objects of bclass will be created which will have different value of a and these objects(objects of bclass) will create corresponding objects of cclass. By 'corresponding' I mean the value of a for cclass will be equal to the value of a for the object of bclass which creates an object of cclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a pointer to the class who created the class 'cclass' in its definition:

```
class cclass: public aclass
{
    bclass * bclass_ref;
    cclass(bclass * ref)
    {
        bclass_ref = ref;
        a = b_class_ref->a;
    }
}
```

Then you add **this** keyword to the definition of your class 'cclass' on the class 'bclass' scope:

```
ob = new cclass(this);
```

Note: Some compilers may throw an error on the constructor of the class 'cclass' all you need to do is make the constructor public.

Edit: I tested the code by myself and you will need to add the definition of the class 'cclass' before the definition of the function 'bclass::func'

Comment: You are probably using an extra pointer to bclass. I have done the same as you have written but i am not using the extra bclass_ref pointer and directly doing a= ref->a.

Comment: Yeah, I maked the definition of bclass_ref for future refence outside the function 'bclass::func', my fault, because it is destroyed when the App exit the function...

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass bclass object to cclass constructor:-

```
class cclass: public aclass
{
   cclass(const bclass& b)
   {
      a = b.a;
   }
}
```

if you ignore other peculiarities in your code.

Answer (score -2):

You would need to pass it as a parameter from your func() method.

> ob = new cclass(this.a);

Answer (score -2):

the keyword "base" permitted access to parent properties

```
base.a = 9
```

for more information check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/ms228387(v=vs.90).aspx)